# Can we automate internal links of large websites?

Tags: seo, links, automation, google-news

Consider a Large website with more than 2,00,000+ Pages like News websites. In News websites we are updating the content daily. Means more than 100+ articles are updated to website daily.
Interlinking between two pages of website consider an article with a particular football club can link to a page with Football category or related pages.
According to SEO this will help to increase the Authority of Page and also helps Google bots to easily crawl the website.
Can we automate this interlinking process? Means if somebody writes an article and uploads in a CMS?I wanted the solution because its a large news website.
And also its suggessted by experts as https://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-101/seo-experts/.

Comment: People do use systems for automatically linking large websites.  I've implemented such systems myself.   Are you asking if you have the ability to do so?   How are we supposed to know that?

Comment: I wanted to know whether we can implement those in drupal platforms. And also steps/procedure to implement it. And also any precautions we need to take in this process?

Answer (score 1):

Auto-linking content is possible and there are sites out there that already do this. As for doing it in Drupal it can be done but this is outside the scope of webmastering and is getting more into programming as you would have to create a custom plugin for Drupal. How it is done, how text which should be linked and where it should link to is more a business and programming decision as well as depending on your needs you may choose to link based on exact copies of article titles in bodies of other pages, or you may decide to link based on contextual tagging of key phrases in the body text, etc.

As for precautions the chances of false links grows very high with an automated process which does not have human supervision. You could combat this by making a suggestion engine so that if the check decides a link may be of benefit it highlights the appropriate text and shows a message saying that a possible link may have been found, show the link to the user and give the user the option of embedding the link. You could even do something similar to the way the related questions list to the right works in that as you type a question it updates the list. If you did the same with the article body then as the user is typing the selection of possible related articles updates and if the end user comes across a relevant article they could click on the link and have it added to the article they are working on currently with the title of the article as the name of the link.

As you can probably gather there are many implementations which in turn dictate procedures and steps which also in turn dictate precautions to take.

Comment: I agree with your answers Chris. The idea of "suggestion engine" is good. Apart from that can we link category page with many article pages will there be any affect on SEO?

Comment: Category pages unless they have content of their own generally aren't ranked rather they are used as a way to identify other pages for indexing. You need to remember sites are ranked these days on the user experience not on the search engine experience so build your site on the basis of helping your site users and allow the ranking to develop organically.